# how to update wikipages automatically using python scripts

Tags: python

I am using a internal wiki for my projects is there anything available so that I can update my wiki entries automatically using a python script? So that I don't need to go always to the wikipage and edit those pages manually.

Thanks,

Beeth

Comment: Does your wiki have an API? This question is incredibly vague.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). Using this, you can essentially automate browser activity